# IIS 7 on Win 2008 R2 does not display images by default

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have some images hosted on the Default Web Site on IIS 7 but when i attempt to browse them IIS blocks the images. Help me please! ))

Comment: may be your browser blocks the images ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I used a few different browsers and it happens only on Win 2008 R2.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This might be the solution:

Check the Static Content checkbox under World Wide Web Services / Common Http Features.

Here is a page with a screenshot:

http://gurustop.net/blog/2009/10/12/funny-problem-windows-7-iis-7-5-images-css-not-showing/

Another page:

http://peterkellner.net/2008/04/01/iis7imageproblem/

Comment: It is really the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Static Content was not selected by default, and who knew that was a thing? :-p

Comment: Saved me when worked finished at the end hours of the night, I exhausted and suddenly an error grinned, Thanks man :)

Answer (score 1):

I found that, with a .NET 4.0 site, the following entry in the web.config caused my images to not get served up:

```
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Removing the **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"**  solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the feature was already installed. What solved the problem was:

1. Uncheck the Static Content checkbox under World Wide Web Services
   / Common Http Features, then restart the server
2. Check the Static Content checkbox under World Wide Web Services /
   Common Http Features.

Answer (score 0):

In your IIS find RequestFiltering. Then right mouse button "Open Feature"
And look throw file extensions that are not allowed to download.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and IIS was configured properly.

The problem was permissions in Windows.

Basically I copied over the Inetpub/wwwroot permissions to the directory I was using and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Now I started thinking, images in the website didn’t show also! I didn’t know whether this was a DB/code issue or related to not showing the CSS, well, maybe something is wrong with IIS installation, right? Well, exactly!!!

https://i0.wp.com/www.gurustop.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/iis-static-content.png?ssl=1